# How to determine if API accepts json in POST Requests - only seems to accept form-data

Tags: json, rest

I have an API that I am posting to that accepts posts from me in Postman if the body is form-data and returns a 201.  If, however, I format the body as JSON, I get back a 400 response indicating all the missing fields - e.g.

```
"errors": [
    {
        "code": "1000",
        "message": "Missing parameter",
        "origin": "first_name"
    },...etc
```

I do not get, however, any indication that JSON is not accepted.  Is there a way that I can determine if the API accepts posts with a JSON Body?  If it does, it this the response I should be getting?

Comment: 1st clue, make sure you validate your json body at: https://jsonlint.com/, besides you didn't mentioned how you are sending json to api. could be that you may have used misconfigured postman or there may be actually your api end point is rejecting post request data in json format

Comment: I verified my json with jsonlint.com - my main question is how to I determine if the end point is accepting or not accepting json.

Comment: I am including content-type as application/json in the header

Comment: to answer that question, you need to add more detail rather than just letting to know error 400, if you have developed API end point, mind sharing piece of code which interacts/handles your json data?

Comment: I did not develop the endpoint - so that's why I am wondering how to determine in the first instance if this endpoint accepts JSON in the body - it clearly accepts form-data as I am able to successfully create records when I use form-data

Comment: A well-behaved REST server would have sent a form-representation which teaches your client about all the stuff it needs to make further requests, such as the target URL, the HTTP operation to use, the media-type to use to marshal the data to a suitable representation format and of course the supported properties a resource has. Without such form support, the service is more or less a black box where you can just use trial & error to learn what the server expects